# How to restrict REST parameters to enum in spring-mvc?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want to restrict REST service parameters by an `enum` as follows:

```
public class enum {
    TEST;
}

@RestController
public class MyRest {
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public Object content(@RequestParam value="list" required=false) List<MyEnum> list) {
    Sysout(list);
  }
}
```

This works great if I call: `/app?list=TEST`.

But when invoking `/app?list=test` (lowercase letters) the rest services does not respond.

How can I eg provide custom values for the enum types to be accepted?

Comment: Solution was to add the following into the rest service controller: `@InitBinder protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     binder.registerCustomEditor(MyEnum.class, new EnumConverter<MyEnum>(MyEnum.class));}`

Answer (score -6):

I am not sure about the way you are doing it. But we can do it in another way.

```
public class enum {
  TEST(1, "TEST");
}

@RestController
public class MyRest {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Object content(@RequestParam value="list" required=false) List<Integer> list) {
    for(Integer int: list)
    sysout(enum.get(int));
  }
}
```

You can pass in a list of integers and map the enum against these int values. Passing a list of integers seems cleaner to me.

Thanks!!

Comment: well but I want my clients to trasmit string values explicit, so integers are no option.

Comment: If you want to convert an enum from an incoming string value use:

    MyEnum.valueOf(inputString.toUpperCase());